# C Program to get the version of jar file

Tags: c

A c program code to get the file version of jar file and we need to compare with some versions and show to the user , we know that it is easy in java but we wanted in c language only

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: http://www.owsiak.org/jar-files-without-version-in-file-name/

Answer (score 2):

use *popen* to execute `unzip -p my.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep 'Bundle-Version'` and get the result

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage : %s <jarfile>\n", *argv);
  else {
    size_t len = strlen(argv[1]) + 56;
    char * s = malloc(len);
    FILE * fp;

    sprintf(s, "unzip -p %s META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep 'Bundle-Version'",
            argv[1]);
    if ((fp = popen(s, "r")) == NULL)
      fprintf(stderr, "error when executing '%s'\n", s);
    else {
      if (fscanf(fp, "Bundle-Version: %50s", s) == 1)
        printf("version '%s'\n", s);
      else
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot get the version\n");
      pclose(fp);
    }

    free(s);
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra p.c
/tmp % ./a.out my.jar 
version '1.5'
```